# Знаки препинания перед словом "это"

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте.

Для "предприятия, в которое очередь за воротами стоит" ( )  это отличный способ набора персонала.

Для него ( ) это хорошо.

Ставится ли перед "это"  знак препинания во втором предложении?

Есть ли разница с первым предложением?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаемый вариант:

(1) Для "предприятия, в которое очередь за воротами стоит," - это отличный способ набора персонала. (2) Для него это хорошо.

Вариант с переносом кавычек: (1) Для  предприятия, в которое "очередь за воротами стоит", - это отличный способ набора персонала.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Грамматика предложений сходна, хотя это СПП и простое предложение, и отличается только наличием распространителя в виде придаточного предложения для дополнения в начале предложения. В обоих случаях "это" - подлежащее, сказуемое является именным.

Такая грамматика не требует постановки тире, и его следует считать авторским, но вот объяснение этого авторского знака может быть интересным.

Попробуем изменить предложение: "Для предприятия, которое и так пользуется популярностью, это отличный способ набора персонала".  В этом случае тире не кажется необходимым, так как изменилась  интонационная структура сообщения. Также не требуется тире в предложении "Для него  это (пз) хорошО" (пз обозначает перелом интонации).

А теперь вернемся к заданному предложению, почему там требуется тире? (1) Для "предприятия, в которое очередь за воротами стоит" (ПЗ) - это отличный способ набора персонала (ПЗ обозначает увеличенную паузу).

В этом случае акцентируется слово "за воротами" (на него падает тоническое ударение), поэтому пауза при прочтении неизбежна. Всё дело в цитате, которую ПРИХОДИТСЯ встраивать в предложение в НЕИЗМЕННОМ виде и которая задает не совсем обычную структуру предложения.

Comment: "Такая грамматика не требует постановки тире, и его следует считать авторским, но вот объяснение этого авторского знака может быть интересным."

Такая грамматика вообще не требует постановки знака?

Comment: Вот, к примеру, предложение: "Для таких предприятий это отличный способ набора персонала". Простое двусоставное предложение с детерминантом в начале, здесь не нужны знаки препинания. Даже если распространить детерминант стандартным способом, они все равно не нужны.  Чтобы поставить тире, нужно распространить детераинант особым способом - так, чтобы  он перестал "читаться" в составе данного предложения.

Comment: Почему вы решили, что ударение падает на "за воротами", а не на "очередь" или "стоит"? Насколько я знаю, пауза акцентирует последнее слово перед ней и первое после нее. То есть "стоит" и "это отличный". Мне кажется, тире неуместно, так как границы цитаты и так обозначены кавычками, после которых делается небольшая пауза.

Comment: Для "предприЯтия, в которое за воротами стоит Очередь", это отличный способ набора персонАла. Стандартный порядок слов не требует тире. Делаем инверсию: Для "предприятия, в которое очередь за ворОтами стоит" - это отличный способ набора персонАла. Перенос ударения на "за воротами" связан с инверсией, так как акцентирование глагола "стоит" искажает смысл.

Answer (score 4):

Первое – сложноподчиненное предложение, второе – простое.

О, кавычек-то не заметил. Кавычки здесь совершенно не мотивированы, просто ни к селу ни к городу. Зачем они? Это просто грамматическая ошибка.
София, как я уже давно заметил, любит мудрствование на пустом месте. ))) Две запятых в первом предложении, и все.

Comment: Мне нравится Ваш стиль, просто талант пропадает. Я бы на Вашем месте писала бы комиксы (смайлик).

Answer (score 2):

При текущем положении кавычек, грамматическая структура двух ваших предложений не просто сходна, а идентична. Все, что в кавычках (а они здесь оправданы только в случае цитирования), является единым членом предложения.

Comment: Вы правы, Марк. Только в случае цитирования или какого-нибудь названия.

Comment: Вы уловили суть вопроса.Знаки аналогичны?

Comment: @verzatrana, я специально не стал писать своё мнение по знакам, так как в области пунктуации я не компетентен. Личное мнение такого - так как придаточное предложение является частью встроенной цитаты, то после кавычек никаких обособлений быть не должно.

Comment: Дело не в том, что мы используем цитаты. Обычно цитаты вписываются в структуру предложения и не требуют к себе особого внимания. Проблемы могут возникнуть в том случае, если цитата не встраивается в предложение, начинает "конфликтовать" с ним, требует для себя особого тонического ударения, как в приведенном примере.

Answer (score 0):

Да, первое это СПП. Тире ставится. Второе простое. Тире не нужно. А что значит " в которое очередь за воротами стоит"? Кто стоит?

Comment: Кто стоит? Сказано же – очередь стоит! )))
Почему тире, а не запятая? И кавычки ни к чему... Зачем мудрить?

Comment: А-а, ясно. Действительно, кавычки не нужны. В СПП предложении после слов это, вот, ставится тире. См. Д.Э. Розенталь. Справочник-практикум. Кавычки изменили бы смысл.